# Unordered list generation in python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, unordered

I'd like to create a million unordered list, `xrange(1, 1000000)` for eg gives me an ordered list. I think I need something like xrange but generates it in an unordered fashion. I think I can generate a list manually by looping around `random.randint`  and some manual checks to guarantee uniqueness of number in list but I reckon it would be time consuming. Any ideas?

Comment: This can easily be solved with `shuffle`, but if you don't want to store entire shuffled array in memory and use random inplace iterator for it, things can get tricky.

Comment: @rr: I'm not sure you can get away with not storing the array in memory if you want to ensure uniqueness?

Comment: @jmetz I'm interested in this as well. I added the comment so that OP is aware of this limitation, because he explicitly uses `xrange` and is clearly concerned about performance.

Comment: Do you need all million numbers? If not, [`random.sample(xrange(1, 1000000), n)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample) might work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import random
L = range(1, 1000000)
random.shuffle(L)  # shuffles in-place
```

on Python3, you will need to use

```
L = list(range(1, 1000000))
random.shuffle(L)  # shuffles in-place
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `random` module from NumPy. Specifically [`np.random.permutation`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.permutation.html#numpy.random.permutation)

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.random.permutation(5)
array([2, 1, 0, 3, 4])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `numpy` you can use [`permutation`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.permutation.html):

```
numpy.random.permutation(10)
>> array([1, 7, 6, 0, 5, 9, 2, 3, 8, 4])
```